# error: unknown type name 'QBuffer'; did you mean 'Qt3DRender::QBuffer'?

Tags: qt, qmake, qbuffer

I have this code:

```cpp
    #include <QBuffer>

    // ---
    
    QString m_parentName;
    
    // ---
    
    QString path = QDir::tempPath();
    path = path + "/" + "temp-" + m_parentName + ".stl";

    QFile file;
    file.setFileName(path);
    file.resize(0); // Clear file contents if any
    file.open(QIODevice::Append);

    // Clear and add 80 bytes of header to QByteArray
    QByteArray temp_ba;
    QBuffer tmpBuffer(&temp_ba); // => error: unknown type name 'QBuffer'; did you mean 'Qt3DRender::QBuffer'?
    tmpBuffer.open(QIODevice::Append);

    tmpBuffer.write("Generated by: " // 14 bytes
                    "My Nice App"    // 11 bytes
                    "My Nice App"    // 11 bytes
                    "My Nice App"    // 11 bytes
                    "My Nice App"    // 11 bytes
                    "My Nice App"    // 11 bytes
                    "My Nice App"    // 11 bytes
                    , 80);

    file.write(temp_ba);
    file.flush();

    tmpBuffer.close();
```

My qmake project file `*.pro` contains:

```
QT += core gui qml quick quickcontrols2 widgets 3dcore 3drender 3dextras 3dinput 3dlogic 3dquick 3drender-private
```

I'm receiving this error:

> error: unknown type name 'QBuffer'; did you mean 'Qt3DRender::QBuffer'?
> qbuffer.h:56:31: note: 'Qt3DRender::QBuffer' declared here

What I'm doing wrong?

[image: Error screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error got resolved by replacing:

```cpp
#include <QBuffer>
```

with:

```cpp
#include <QtCore/QBuffer>
```

Not sure why? Namespace conflict?

Comment: it's possibly library version conflicts, afaik <QtCore/QBuffer> is new style